# How to get Custom ViewCell from XIB to viewController in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a custom table view cell from a XIB. I'm referring to this article here. I'm facing two issues.

I created a .xib file with a UITableViewCell object dragged on to it. I created a subclass of UITableViewCell and want to get data . from this custom class to main class

Comment: Please show what you have tried and let us know what the actual issue is. Also you are not linking the mentioned article.

Answer (score 1):

You're not linking to the article you mentioned, but going by what you said in your question, it seems like you're trying to drag a table view cell into your view. What you should be doing is giving your view in the xib a custom tableviewcell class.

It's easiest just to subclass it when you create the xib file ([As shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vldmn.png)).

This will also create a class file where in you can add outlets etc.